# The chromatic number of the union of two graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, coding-theory

Let $G_n$ be the graph on the set of all binary strings of length $n$ with two strings adjacent whenever they are Hamming distance $2$ away from each other, or one of them lies below another one; thus, for instance, $G_2=K_4$, and $G_3$ has $25$ edges. What is the chromatic number of $G_n$?

There is a simple, but not quite obvious construction showing that $\chi(G_n)\le n(n+1)/2+1$, and I am interested in a matching lower bound. Computations give
$$ \chi(G_1)=2,\ \chi(G_2)=4,\ \chi(G_3)=5,\ \chi(G_4)=9, $$
$$ \chi(G_5)=12,\ \chi(G_6)=16,\ \text{and}\ \chi(G_7)\le 17. $$
(The first five values are easy to compute, the last two are reported by [Gordon Royle](https://mathoverflow.net/users/1492/gordon-royle) in the comments.)

---

*An update.* The colorings I am interesting in are of a special nature: if the strings $s$ and $t$ are same-colored, then (identifying strings with sets) also $s\setminus t$ and $t\setminus s$ are same-colored. Let $\chi^*(G)$ denote the smallest number of colors needed to properly color the graph $G$ in this special way. Is it true that $\chi^*(G_n)=(1/2+o(1))n^2$? That, say,  $\chi^*(G_n)>(1/4+o(1))n^2$?

Comment: Can you expand on the upper bound construction?

Comment: @JoshuaZ: sure; color each vertex with the scalar product of the corresponding string and the vector $(1,2,\dotsc,n)$.

Comment: what do you mean by lying below?

Comment: @FedorPetrov: one of the corresponding subsets of the $n$-element set being contained in another one.

Comment: Here is a nice $17$-colouring of $G_7$ where I am using subsets of $\{0,1,\ldots,6\}$ to represent the vertices. Let $\sigma = (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)$ be a cyclic permutation and let $\tau$ be the complement map on the subsets.  Let $F= \{013, 124, 235, 346, 450, 561, 602\}$ be the Fano plane and set $C = F \cup F^\tau$.  Then take $D = \{0, 16, 25, 34, 124, 135, 236, 456\}$ and its seven rotations under powers of $\sigma$, and $D^\tau$ and its seven rotations under powers of $\sigma$. Then one colour class for each of $\emptyset$ and the entire set, making a total of 17 classes.

Comment: @GordonRoyle: interesting - and quite far from $7^2/2$...

Comment: So $G_6$ has chromatic number $16$ - this took quite a long time to compute, almost all of which was spent searching in vain for a $15$-colouring. I think it will be hard to get close to an exact answer.

Comment: @GordonRoyle: thank you very much for the contribution. Interestingly, also this value is very close to $n^2/2$; looks like $n=7$ is a sort of exception. An exact answer may be too good to hope for, but $(1/2+o(1))n^2$, or even $(1/4+o(1))n^2$ would be great to have.

Comment: @bof: do you mean $\chi(G_n)\ge\lfloor3n/2\rfloor+1$? Anyway, I don't have any lower bound besides the trivial $\chi(G_n)\ge n+1$.

Comment: @bof: incidentally, computations suggest that $\lfloor 3n/2\rfloor+1$ is, indeed, the clique number of $G_n$.

Comment: I added a coding theory tag as this question is clearly relevant to binary codes.

Comment: I think if we are happy to believe that $\chi(G_6) = 16$ then we should also conclude that $\chi(G_7) = 17$ (equality, rather than inequality).

Comment: @GordonRoyle Because $\chi(G_n)\lt\chi(G_{n+1})$ , right?

Comment: As per the comment by @bof, we know that the chromatic number strictly increases.

Comment: Summarizing: $$\chi(G_{2n})=(n+1)^2\text{ for }n=0,1,2,3;$$ $$\chi(G_{2n+1})=(n+1)^2+1\text{ for }n=0,1,3;$$ $$\chi(G_5)=12.$$ Too bad $\chi(G_5)\ne10$.

Answer (score 9):

This is a comment, not an answer, but it will be more convenient to post it as an answer. Consider the vertices of $G_n$ as subsets of $[n]=\{1,\dots,n\}$.

**Observation 1.** $\chi(G_n)\ge\left\lfloor\frac{3n}2\right\rfloor+1$.

This is because $G_n$ contains a clique of that size, namely,
$\varnothing,\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,4\},\{1,2,3,4,\},\{1,2,3,4,5\},\dots$.

**Observation 2.** The OP noted that $\chi(G_n)\le\binom{n+1}2+1=\frac{n^2+n+2}2$. For odd $n$ this bound can be improved to $\chi(G_n)\le\frac{n^2+3}2$.

The vertices $\varnothing$ and $[n]$ get their own colors. If $1\le|X|\le n-1$, color $X$ with the ordered pair
$$\left(\sum_{x\in X}x\mod(n+1),\ \left\lceil\frac{|X|}2\right\rceil\right).$$
This is a proper coloring, so (assuming $n$ is odd)
$$\chi(G_n)\le2+(n+1)\cdot\frac{n-1}2=\frac{n^2+3}2.$$

**Observation 3.** The clique number $\omega(G_n)$ is exactly $\left\lfloor\frac{3n}2\right\rfloor+1$.

We showed in Observation 1 that $\omega(G_n)\ge\left\lfloor\frac{3n}2\right\rfloor+1$. Let us prove by induction that $\omega(G_n)\le\left\lfloor\frac{3n}2\right\rfloor+1$.

We may assume $n\ge2$. Let $\mathcal C$ be a maximal clique in $G_n$. Let $\mathcal C_h=\{X\in\mathcal C:|X|=h\}$. Choose $h$ so that $0\lt h\lt n$ and $\mathcal C_h\ne\varnothing$.

If $\bigcup\mathcal C_h=[n]$ and $\bigcap\mathcal C_h=\varnothing$, then $|\mathcal C|=|\mathcal C_h|+2\le n+2\le\left\lfloor\frac{3n}2\right\rfloor+1$. Otherwise, choose $X\in\{\bigcup\mathcal C_h,\ \bigcap\mathcal C_h\}$ so that $0\lt|X|\lt n$, and let $k=|X|$. Then every element of $\mathcal C$ is a subset or superset of $X$. Since $0\lt k\lt n$, by induction we have
$$|\mathcal C|\le\omega(G_k)+\omega(G_{n-k})-1\le\left\lfloor\frac{3k}2\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{3(n-k)}2\right\rfloor+1\le\left\lfloor\frac{3n}2\right\rfloor+1.$$

Comment: Some more computational snippets: the cliques you found are the unique maximum clique (up to equivalence under the automorphism group) for $G_4$, $G_6$ and $G_8$. For $G_5$, $G_7$ and $G_9$ there are other classes of equally-large cliques, but none larger.

Comment: So I liked your original proof that if $|\mathcal{C}_h| = 1$ for some $h$, then the result follows. Did you decide that it was not so obvious to prove that there must be a layer containing just one vertex of the clique?

Answer (score 8):

In a similar vein to $\chi^{\ast}(G_n)$, we can define a quantity $\chi^{\ast \ast}(G_n)$ as follows: Suppose you have an abelian group $M$ and a set $S=\{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\}\subset M$, such that for every non-empty subset $T\subset \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ we have
$$\sum_{i\in T}x_i\neq 0.$$
Then you can color the graph $G_n$ by assigning the color $\sum_{i\in T}x_i$ to the vertex corresponding to $T$. It is not difficult to check that this gives a proper coloring of $G_n$ and that it satisfies the extra condition in the definition of $\chi^{\ast}$. Then we define $\chi^{\ast \ast}(G_n)$ as the smallest amount of colors used in such a coloring as we go over all choices of $S$ and $M$. Thus we have the following bounds
$$\chi(G_n)\le \chi^{\ast}(G_n)\le \chi^{\ast\ast}(G_n).$$

The quantity $\chi^{\ast \ast}(G_n)$ was originally studied in the paper

> R. B. Eggleton, P. Erdős, ["Two combinatorial problems in group theory"](https://old.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1972-25.pdf) Acta Arith. 21 (1972),
> 111-116

where it was shown that $\chi^{\ast \ast}(G_n)\le\lceil\frac{n^2}{2}\rceil+1$. They make the conjecture that this is always equality but this was later shown to be false already for $n=7$. They also conjectured that an optimal coloring among abelian groups can always be achieved using a cyclic group.

As far as lower bounds, Olson showed that $\chi^{\ast \ast}(G_n)\geq \frac{n^2}{9}$ in the paper

> J. E. Olson, "Sums of sets of group elements", Acta Arith. 28 (1975), 147–156

and I believe that the best known bound is $\chi^{\ast \ast}(G_n)\geq \frac{n^2}{6}$ from

> W. Gao, M. Huang, W. Hui, Y. Li, C. Liu, J. Peng, ["Sums of sets of abelian group elements"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022314X19302793), J. Number Theory, 208 (2020), 208–229

In the end, this is all to say that if one were able to show a lower bound of $\left(\frac{1}{4}+o(1)\right)n^2$ for $\chi(G_n)$ or $\chi^{\ast}(G_n)$ this would significantly improve what is known about $\chi^{\ast\ast}(G_n)$, so it seems like this can be filed under "open problem" for the time being.

Comment: Great job - this, in fact, was my original motivation! But who knows, maybe this is the ``right'' approach. Problems often become easier when irrelevant details are stripped out.

Comment: Is $k$ equal to $n$ here?

Comment: @GordonRoyle Yes, thank you for catching that!